# How to get the sum of the columns H12_LC, F12_LC, Sales_LC?

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query, I am trying to get the sum of H12_LC, F12_LC, and Sales_LC in one row.

```
Select C.region,C.Project_number, C.Country_Name, C.currency_rate, C.snapshot_date,C.H12_LC, C.F12_LC, C.Sales_LC
from 
(

select B.Region, B.Project_number, B.Country_Name,B.Currency_Rate,B.snapshot_Date,
sum(H12) as H12_LC,
sum(F12) as F12_LC,
sum(Sales_Curr_mth) as Sales_LC
from
(
Select A.[region],A.Region_NCC,A.[Country_Name],CURR.[Currency_Rate],A.[Project_Number],

      (sum(Underrun_Cost)-sum(Overrun_Cost)) AS Net_NCC_Cost,
      A.Snapshot_Date,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Forecast' and POC.Header_1 = 'Curr.mth.' and POC.Report_Param = 'Risk Contingency' then POC.Adjusted_Value/CURR.Currency_Rate 
else null
end as H12_USD,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Budget' and POC.Header_1 = 'Upd.OEC' and POC.Report_Param = 'Risk Contingency' then POC.Adjusted_Value/CURR.Currency_Rate
else null
end as F12_USD,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Forecast' and POC.Header_1 = 'Curr.mth.' and POC.Report_Param = ' Sales' then POC.Adjusted_Value/CURR.Currency_Rate
else null
end as Sales_Curr_mth_USD,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Forecast' and POC.Header_1 = 'Curr.mth.' and POC.Report_Param = 'Risk Contingency' then POC.Adjusted_Value 
else null
end as H12,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Budget' and POC.Header_1 = 'Upd.OEC' and POC.Report_Param = 'Risk Contingency' then POC.Adjusted_Value
else null
end as F12,
case when POC.Header_2 = 'Forecast' and POC.Header_1 = 'Curr.mth.' and POC.Report_Param = ' Sales' then POC.Adjusted_Value
else null
end as Sales_Curr_mth
       from
(
       ........
) AS A

left join [PROJ_REP].[Project_POC] as POC 

)B
       )C
      order by C.snapshot_Date
```

Right now my output is shown below;

[image: Output]

Can you tell me how to get one record as my output?

[image: Desired Output]

thanks
Bob

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be extremely helpful.  As is, your query won't run without a `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like all of your other columns are static, it looks like you want a `group by`. I'm going to assume here that you want to treat `null` as 0:

```
with YourCurrentQuery as (
  Select C.region,C.Project_number, C.Country_Name, C.currency_rate, C.snapshot_date,C.H12_LC, C.F12_LC, C.Sales_LC
  ...
)
select
  region,
  Project_number,
  Country_Name,
  currency_rate,
  snapshot_date,
  isnull(sum(H12_LC), 0) H12_LC,
  isnull(sum(F12_LC), 0) F12_LC,
  isnull(sum(Sales_LC), 0) Sales_LC
from
  YourCurrentQuery
group by
  region,
  Project_number,
  Country_Name,
  currency_rate,
  snapshot_date
```

This will add all of the columns together, treating nulls as 0 (`isnull`), and then group the rows together and add the result.

Comment: thank you for your response, I want to have the output as shown in the picture. Instead of three records, one record summing up the values.

Comment: I misunderstood you to mean to combine all three columns into one. I updated my answer to leave these as separate columns.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Ah--your posted query has an `order by`. If you're wrapping it in a subquery, you'll need to remove the `order by` clause. You can, optionally, move it to the outermost query (the one I posted) after the `group by` clause. `group by ... snapshot_date order by snapshot_date`

Comment: With Net as (Query),    
select region,
Project_number,
  Country_Name,
  currency_rate,
  snapshot_date,
  isnull(sum(H12_LC), 0) H12_LC,
  isnull(sum(F12_LC), 0) F12_LC,
  isnull(sum(Sales_LC), 0) Sales_LC
from Net

Comment: It says Incorrect syntax near select statement, Can you tell me where I am doing wrong